# How to auto-grow Spring @ModelAttribute command class with a List of interface objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to bind a `command` class that contains a `List` of objects that implement an interface in `Spring (Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE)`.

- Command class

  ```
  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public class CarInternetContentEditFormCommand implements EditFormCommand {

      @Valid
      @NotEmpty
      @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = CarInternetContentForm.class)
      private List<EditForm> editForms;

      public CarInternetContentEditFormCommand() {
          this.editForms = new ArrayList<>();
      }

      public EditForm getEditForm() {
          if (this.editForms.isEmpty()) {
              return new CarInternetContentForm();
          }
          return this.editForms.get(0);
      }

      @Override
      public void setEditForm(EditForm form) {
          if (this.editForms.isEmpty()) {
              this.editForms = new ArrayList<>();
          }
          this.editForms.add(form);
      }
  }
  ```
- Error trace

> org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'editForms' of bean class [com.phistory.mvc.cms.command.CarInternetContentEditFormCommand]: Could not instantiate property type [com.phistory.mvc.cms.form.EditForm] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.phistory.mvc.cms.form.EditForm]: Specified class is an interface

When the view renders, the `editForms` list in the `command` is empty, and in my view I try to bind element number 0, like so:

```
<@spring.formInput "CICEFC.editForms[0].link", "class=form-control", "text"/>
```

Therefore Spring tries to auto-grow the list and instantiate an `EditCommand` object, which is obviously an interface and it doesn't know how to.

Is there a way to tell Spring how to do this? I have tried registering a `PropertyEditor` for the command class but it never gets invoked.

Comment: What happens if you declare editForms as  ArrayList<EditForm> editForms; Whoever is complaining, does not like interface, so you need to pass a concrete class.

Comment: Yes I know this, Spring is complaining it cannot instantiate a `List` of `EditForm` because it's an interface, but I have other `command` classes that have a single `EditForm` object, and by using 'Jackson''s annotation

    `@JsonDeserialize(as = ConcreteEditCommand.class)`

It can instantiate it, the problem is with Collections, I was expecting there to be a way to tell Spring how to instantiate them